# Is it possible to get the X11 file descriptor that Qt uses so I can do a poll() on it?

Tags: qt, select, x11, file-descriptor, epoll

I am looking for the X11 file descriptor which I want to add to my list of connections to poll(). I already have a waiting loop that works just fine, but in this one other application, I also want some Qt windows and widgets.

If I were to program with my own X windows I would just use the file descriptor I get when I connect to X11.

```
Display *d = XOpenDisplay(getenv("DISPLAY"));
int fd = XConnectionNumber(d);
// add fd as one of the file descriptors to listen to in my poll()
```

Is there a way retrieve that file descriptor from Qt? (I understand it will be specific to X-Windows)

For those interested, the source code for my existing `poll()` loop is here:

https://github.com/m2osw/snapwebsites/blob/470847e384a4299c4d0cfe907e68cb323194ccd0/libsnapwebsites/src/snapwebsites/snap_communicator.cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QX11Info::display()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qx11info.html#display) will give you the Display, and then I guess you could use XConnectionNumber() like in your example. I’m not sure how well Qt will work if its event loop isn’t running the show, but it’s worth a shot.

Comment: The fd is just for the poll(). To execute the Qt events, I intend to call the `QtCode::eventDispatcher()->processEvents()` function to execute the events.